# Random Slopes - Categorical Variables

Tags: mixed-model, terminology

I know that a a "random slopes" model usually has both intercepts and slopes models varying randomly across groups.

Was reading the classic example with sleepstudy data. I understood that when you using a random slope model, you creating a personal intercept and a personal slope for each subject. My predictor variable in this example was Days which is a quantitative variable.

Wanted to ask if in a random slope model, the corresponding variable of Days can be a categorical variable.

Lets say I have treatment effect with 2 different groups, and I want to allow the effect of treatments to differ between subjects. If lets say I also have a random intercept thats making my model a random slope model?

Comment: You probably can - it sounds like some kind of anova model with random effects. Could you be a bit more explicit about your experimental design? What is your categorical variable, do you only observe one value per person and such details?

Comment: @Ute The example was something that come in my mind when I was trying to explain it. I find something else now, cause I dont know if I can send links you can search this: Mixed Effects Models 3: Random Slopes by Yury Zablotski. As I can see he is using categorical variables and still the definition is a random slope.